# Halachic/sociological basis to support the split-apart beds for a nida couple?

Tags: marriage, sleep, popular-culture, niddah

I'd seen a clip from a TV show that's about Orthodox Israelis in which a married couple has a bed that's one big frame, upon which two mattresses can either slide together or apart, depending on the time of the month.

As there's a common frame I strongly assume even when the mattresses are apart, you could feel something when the other person rolled over or moved around, so this is not a halachically valid option.

So where did the TV producers get this idea? Are there people that use this setup? Is there a halachic source (perhaps minority) for it? Or did someone in the props department just decide it looked cool, without checking their religion consultants?

Comment: when you ass-u-me...

Comment: "ASUM" = "Avno Sakino UMasao" -- it causes everyone to stumble.

Comment: How far do the beds move apart? Movement might be a geder against touching (compare with the halacha of placing an object between spouses on a moveable platform).  If the beds move far enough apart, that might circumvent the problem.

Comment: These types of beds are relatively common in stores in Israel; they're referred to as מיטה יהודית, a Jewish bed. You can see pictures here: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=opera&hs=BFr&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=991&bih=632&tbs=itp:photo&tbm=isch&q=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94+%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA&revid=0&sa=X&ei=UMAnT7ufB8mV-wbsj53GBQ&ved=0CEgQxw4

Answer (score 3):

I did not see the show but we have this type of bed.  One bed is stationary and is connected to the headboard while the other bed is moveable. The movable bed looks like it's attached to the headboard when you move it but it's not.  In reality the movable bed is it's own bed and you could even put it in another room and it wouldn't look strange but the non-movable bed would look really strange on it's own.  lol

Comment: Hi Baruch, welcome to Mi Yodea! It seems you're not talking exactly about the question, but something similar. Please make sure the answer fits the question. Good luck!

Comment: @JNF, it sounds to me like it very well could be what was seen by the asker.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, Baruch is mentionning seperate beds with a shared headboard - not a single frame.

Answer (score 1):

Two beds on one frame is permissible, as long as the beds themselves don't touch while the wife is in niddah.

I have even seen furniture companies make this type of bed specifically for the religious Jewish community.

http://www.yoatzot.org/question.php?id=6479

Also see here, #26
http://www.milknhoney.co.il/holy/7.html
(this site also leaves a footnote, from where this list is derived).

Unfortunately, I can't find a picture of the two bed / one frame designs that I have personally seen in furniture stores.  However, image #5 on the site below demonstrates another way that would work:

http://www.oddee.com/item_96939.aspx

Comment: Will, the article you linked to contradicts your assertion in your answer. It says that if the two mattresses share the same "base" (which I read as the commonly used term "bed-frame") then it is a problem. It is only not a problem if the outer rim of the headboard/footboard of the bed are not connected to a shared base. I don't know what show Shalom is referencing, but if I understand him correctly, the beds are supported by the same physical structure, which merely allows the beds to slide apart. If that is the case, then it is not adequate for Niddah purposes.

Comment: I didn't see the same TV show that Shalom is talking about - but in the the two beds / one frame that I've seen, the beds each have their own base - they merely slide across grooved channels, together or apart, as needed.  Thus, the two beds on one frame (again, the ones that I have seen) do not share a base, and are permissible to be used, pushed apart, with ones wife who is a niddah.

Comment: Are the grooves not considered a base?

Comment: @SethJ no the grooves would be a frame...

Comment: But if the base is in some way connected via the frame, then it is a problem. How can they be sliding on a groove but not be connected?

Comment: If there's not enough space in the room to separate the mattresses you can even just put a divider between them.  It's a common problem in Israel where apartments are very small.

Answer (score 1):

[This article addresses the question](http://www.yoatzot.org/question.php?id=6479). If the two mattresses share the same "base" (which I read as the commonly used term "bed-frame"), then it is a problem. It is only not a problem if the outer rim of the headboard/footboard of the bed are not connected to a common base.  I don't know what show you are referencing, but if I understand you correctly, the beds are supported by the same physical structure, which merely allows the beds to slide apart.  If that is the case, then it is not adequate for Niddah purposes.  I would assume that it is either a mistake on the part of the props department, or else it is a common misconception that some religious couples in Israel rely upon and which was then employed by the show.

Comment: A base is not a bedframe, a base is a base and a bedframe is a bedframe.  Most beds consist of three parts, the bedframe (which may or may not contains the headboard and footboard), the base, and the mattress.  In simple beds the base is a piece of wood that is the size of the matress or larger, in fancy  beds, the base looks like a mattress but is hollow.   Just for a point of reference, most California king sized beds come with two bases and one bedframe.

Comment: @avi In standard beds (ie., not full bedroom units with headboard, etc.) the "bed frame" is a metal frame on legs or wheels (often interchangeable) that support the mattress (and sometimes box spring). It looks like this: http://www.samsclub.com/sams/shop/product.jsp?productId=103236&pid=CSE_Froogle&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=159719  Not having seen the show, I cannot be sure what Shalom is referring to, but I'm pretty confident that the article is referring to something with this sort of thing supporting the actual mattresses. If they are separate, fine; if they are connected/shared, not so.

Comment: Cont... Whether it is metal or wood is inconsequential. What matters is whether or not some unit is jointly supporting both beds. If there is a surrounding unit enclosing the beds, which each has its own support structure, it is ok. If the enclosing unit is connected to them, or if the support structure itself is somehow connected, even if they slide apart on rails, it is a problem.

Comment: The slats of wood, or metal that goes across the bedframe to keep the mattress from sagging in the center would be the "base"

Comment: @avi I understand from several of your posts that you are in Israel, and I know that beds in Israel are generally different from beds here in the U.S. That's why I stated that I was interpreting "base" to refer to what we call here a "bed frame". Do a search on Google for "bed frame" and you get product listings like the one I linked. That's not the point. The point is what is the thing that we are talking about? We are talking about support structures for the mattresses. If the mattresses share one support, no good; if they are separate, ok.

Comment: Cont... I was identifying for American readers what is meant by "base".

Comment: Compare these two links... One is selling bed frames, the other is selling Matress bases.  There is no different here between American and Israel, except that in Israel our bases are a lot less comfortable. http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/range/10376/10636/
http://www.thesleepshop.com/store/pc/Bed-Frame-Parts-and-Hardware-c34.htm

The important part here is that the frame lifts up the mattress, but it does not support the part where a person sleeps, only the base does that.

Comment: @avi We are saying the same thing. I was trying to simplify things for the reader(s) of my answer by clarifying what a "base" is. In the U.S. a "base" as used in the article is what we call a "bed frame". Look at the side panel in second link you provided. Select the link for "bed frames" and then choose "standard bed frames". Every item shown is a metal structure that supports the mattress.

Comment: We aren't saying the same thing but that is ok. I'm sure other readers can figure it out by now.  As I suspected, the "base" in the answer here is referring to what you might know as the "box-spring"

Comment: If there's not enough space in the room to separate the mattresses you can even just put a divider between them. It's a common problem in Israel where apartments are very small.